# Windows 10 computer will receive mouse but not keyboard input

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

Once or twice a day, my keyboard will stop working. I can still use the mouse, but if I click on an application in the toolbar it acts as though I'm attempting to open it as an administrator, with the "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?" dialog. In Google Chrome, if I use the scroll wheel it zooms in and out, as if the Ctrl key is being pushed. I can use the mouse to sign out, then the keyboard works normally again and the problem goes away.

If I attempt a remote connection from some other computer while this is happening, the connection never completes but the problem computer goes black and has to be shut down.

I thought it might be the keyboard, but I bought a new keyboard and the same thing happens. I also tried different USB ports and cables for the keyboard. I'm not sure what to try next.

**UPDATE:** When the keyboard input stopped working, I tried unplugging the keyboard and plugging in a different one. It did not seem to have any affect. Once I signed out and back in it worked again as usual.

Comment: You could have a virus (keylogger) or spyware. Have you checked for these?

Comment: I looked up a couple ways to find keyloggers. I couldn't really identify any suspicious processes. Many suggest the free version of Malwarebytes, but they're a few years old. Is that still a recommended tool? I'm not sure what could have infected my computer. I don't download torrents or pirated software and aside from a few open source tools, pretty much everything on my computer is commercial applications.

Comment: Malwarebytes anti-malware is still a decent tool. The software itself may not be up-to-date, but their definitions are, and those matter. hitman pro is another tool you can use to check for malware. Note, they are not virusscanners. You need a scan with one of those too. But it could be something else. Given that replacing the hardware doesn't fix it, it looks like a software problem.

Comment: Malwarebytes did not find any threats. I'll try a more complete anti-virus program later today (I'm considering this https://www.comodo.com/business-security/network-protection/rescue-disk.php ). I also saw a suggestion on a related question to open up the on-screen keyboard to see if a keypress is being registered. I'll try that if I am able to have the app open when it happens again.

Comment: Your update suggests it was a driver issue afterall